This page isn't 't working127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times
I want to create middleware where when I want to access a website page I have to do a second login first, and if I don't have a token then the page will redirect to the login page. I entered the code into my middleware but what appears on the website is the error
**
"This page isn't 't working127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try deleting your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"**
and in my terminal a loop occurs on the second-login page. I am using laravel 11
here's my controller code
public function showLoginForm()
    {
        $pageTitle = 'LOGIN';
        return view('auth.login', ['pageTitle' => $pageTitle]);
    }

    // Handle the login request
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $response = Http::withOptions(['verify'=> false])
        ->post('MYAPI/LOGIN', [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);

        Log::info('Login response:', $response->json());

        if ($response->successful()) {
            $token = $response['token'];
            session(['api_token' => $token]);
            return redirect()->route('login-second');
        }

        return back()->withErrors(['login' => 'Email atau password salah']);
    }

    // Get token for SSO
    private function get_token()
    {
        $response = Http::WithOptions(['verify' => false])
        ->post('MYAPI/LOGIN', [
            'email' => 'MYEMAIL',
            'password' => 'MYPASSWORD',
        ]);

        $res = $response->json();
        return $res['token'] ?? null;
    }

    // Display the second login form
    public function showSecondLoginForm()
    {
        $token = $this->get_token();
        return view('auth.login-second', ['token' => $token]);
    }

    public function showSecondLoginFormx(){
        echo "TEST";
        // return view('coba');
    }

    public function secondLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $this->get_token();
        $response = Http::withOptions(['verify'=>false])
        ->withToken($token)
        ->post('MYAPI/LOGIN-SECOND', [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'token' => $token
        ]);
        Log::info('Second login response:', $response->json());
        $data = $response->json();

        if (isset($data['data'])) {
            if ($data['data']['login'] == true) {
                session([
                    'sso_data' => $data['data'],
                ]);
                return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', $data['data']['message']);
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['secondlogin' => $data['data']['message']]);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['secondlogin' => 'Invalid response from SSO service.']);
    }

and this is my route
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Middleware\EnsureSecondLogin;

// Rute yang tidak memerlukan autentikasi
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Login
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

// Login kedua
Route::get('/login-second', [AuthController::class, 'showSecondLoginForm'])->name('login-second');
Route::post('/login-second', [AuthController::class, 'secondLogin'])->name('login-second.submit');

// Rute yang memerlukan autentikasi
Route::middleware([EnsureSecondLogin::class])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/search', [AuthController::class, 'search'])->name('search');
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AuthController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/profile', [AuthController::class,'profile'])->name('profile');
    Route::get('/pegawai', [AuthController::class,'pegawai'])->name('pegawai');
    Route::post('/cari-pegawai', [AuthController::class, 'searchPegawai'])->name('cari-pegawai');
    Route::get('/api/profil-pegawai/{nip}', [AuthController::class, 'getProfile']);
    Route::get('/api/profile/{nip}', [AuthController::class, 'getProfileByNip'])->name('profile.by.nip');
    Route::get('/change-password', [AuthController::class, 'showChangePasswordForm'])->name('show-change-password-form');
    Route::post('/change-password', [AuthController::class, 'changePassword'])->name('change-password');
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
    Route::get('/coba',[AuthController::class, 'coba'])->name('coba');
});

Route::get('/coba',[AuthController::class, 'coba'])->name('coba');


this is my middleware
class EnsureSecondLogin
{
    // File: app/Http/Middleware/EnsureSecondLogin.php

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (!$request->session()->has('api_token')) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        if (!$request->session()->has('sso_data')) {
            return redirect('/login-second');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }


and my app.php
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(append: [
            EnsureSecondLogin::class
        ]);
    })

When accessing the website there is no repetition of the same page, and you can use middleware for the login process

You have added the middleware in app.php in the function withMiddleware which means that it will run for every route in web.php, even /login. This causes the redirect loop. Using Route::middleware([EnsureSecondLogin::class]) in routes/web.php should be enough.
